# Separable ordinary differential equation -- where was my mistake?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm attempting to find the general solution of the following:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} =-5\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$

The answer is supposed to be (according to an online calculator):

$$y = \frac{e^{5c}}{x^5}$$

Where $c$ is some constant. Here's my work:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} =-5\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$

$$-\frac{1}{5y} dy= \frac{1}{x} dx $$

Integrating both sides gets one to:

$$\frac{-\ln(y)}{5} + c_1 = \ln x + c_2$$

$$\frac{-\ln(y)}{5}  = \ln x + c_3$$

$$\ln(y) = -5\ln x - 5c_3$$

$$y = e^{-5\ln x - 5c_3}$$

$$y = \frac{x^{-5}}{e^{5c_3}}$$

$$y = \frac{x^{-5}}{e^{5c}}$$

I seem to have the answer for $\frac{1}{y}$ rather than $y$. Where was my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the same answer, you just don't realize it.

$C$ is a generalized constant.  You can do a lot to it, and it is still just a constant --  $C, 2C, C+D, \ln C$ still just a constant.  There is no need to show these operations.  You can just carry the constant along and keep calling it $C.$

$e^{5c} = \frac 1{e^{5c}} = C$

next.

$x^{-5} = \frac 1{x^5}$

Update:

When you have intial conditions...

$\frac {y'}{y} = -\frac {5}{x}\\
\ln y = -5\ln x + C$

Now you could choose to apply the intial conditions and solve for $C$ and sometimes this is the best time to do so.

$y(2) = 1\\
0 = -5\ln 2 + C\\
C = 5\ln 2$

and then carry that along

$\ln y = \ln (x^{-5}) + 5\ln 2\\
y = e^{\ln (x^{-5}) + 5\ln 2}\\
y = e^{\ln (x^{-5})} e^{5\ln 2}\\
y = 32x^{-5}$

Alternatively, you can wait until a later time (the end).

$\ln y = -5\ln x + C\\
y = Cx^{-5}\\
1 = C 2^{-5}\\
C = 2^5$

I usually wait until the end, but sometimes it is easier to do it earlier.

Comment: So does is it not matter if the constant is $C$ or $C^{-1}$ in that case? Because the constant in the solution is in the numerator.

Comment: Correct.  Once you solve for $C$ based on the initial conditions, you will need to keep track.  But, until that time, you can be really lazy.

Comment: In that case, what if $y(2) =1$? My arrangement with the constants won't change the particular solution?

Comment: @sangstar I have added some discussion on initial conditions.

Answer (score 2):

The answers are the same (look at the power of $x$), but with different integration constants.

Comment: This is a comment rather answer. For a person with 5 gold and 43k reps, not suit to have a such answer.

Comment: @MyGlasses If this was put as a comment, this would pretty much answer the question, which is discouraged: *"Avoid answering questions in comments"*

Answer (score 1):

$$y=\frac{x^{-5}}{e^{5c}}=\frac{e^{-5c}}{x^5}=\frac{e^{5d}}{x^5}$$

where $d=-c$. The solutions are equivalent.